# profile completness meter in cakephp 2.0

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I have to display profile completness meter in cakePHP 2.0. I have found several but not find any script for it. If any one know any script for this in php or cakephp 2.0. please help me.

thanks in advance..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for help. I got solution of my problem.

```
SELECT SUM((`field1` = '') + (`field2` IS NULL) + (`field3` = ''))  FROM profiles where id = 1
```

Where if field is string type the `=''` , if field default value set `NULL` then `IS NULL` and if field type is int then use `=0`.

thanks all of yoou once again.

Answer (score 1):

Like a progressbar? jQuery UI has a progressbar that's shiny and easy to use and theme: [jQuery UI Progressbar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/)

Comment: thanks nyson but is there any easy way to find out how may fields are empty or full in profile table with respected user.